# Possibility to put a function / parameter to a button?

Tags: android, button

Hello I develop an application under android, on my code I block a can finally I would like to avoid creating redundant pages, on my code I have an endroid a page with several button that then display a list view, qaund on supports On a button this app a page that will process the information and go looking for them on the bdd except that I would avoid to replicate this page by so many buttons, what I would like to know if it is possible to pass a parameter to Identify button, or other solution?

Here is my code with the different button (I did not put all the buttons yet):

```
    package ddec.applicationddec;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;



/**
 * Created by Natsu on 22/04/2017.
 */

public class MaterielAssocie extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.materiel_associe);

        // creation de notre bouton pour la list view du matériel : les imprimantes
        Button btn_list_imp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_list_imp);
        btn_list_imp.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MaterielAssocie.this, Mat_asso_imp.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Log.i("List imprimantes","bouton de recherche pour le matériel");
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }

        });

        // creation de notre bouton pour la list view du matériel : les ordinateur
        Button btn_list_ordi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_list_ordi);
        btn_list_ordi.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MaterielAssocie.this, Mat_asso_imp.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Log.i("List des ordinateurs","bouton de recherche pour le matériel");
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }

        });



    }}
```

Here is my page that fetches the data and puts it in the list view :

```
 package ddec.applicationddec;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Natsu on 22/04/2017.
 */

public class Mat_asso_imp extends Activity {
    private ListView lv;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public static ArrayList<imprimante> detail = new ArrayList<>();
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_materiel);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMa);
        chargerJeuDessaie();
        rafraichirListView();
    }

    private void chargerJeuDessaie()
    {
        progressDialog = progressDialog.show(this,"Affichage du matériel : imprimante","Telechargement en cours");
        MonAsyncTaskHttp monAsyncTaskHttp = new MonAsyncTaskHttp() {

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
                super.onPostExecute(o);
                Mat_asso_imp.detail.clear();
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(o.toString());
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        imprimante imp = imprimante.factoryImp(jsonObject);
                        Mat_asso_imp.detail.add(imp);

                        rafraichirListView();


                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        };
        monAsyncTaskHttp.execute("requete=getLesecoleetimp&etab="+ search_ville.etabSELECT.getId());
    }

    public void rafraichirListView() {
        ArrayAdapter<imprimante> imprimanteadapter = new ArrayAdapter<imprimante>(Mat_asso_imp.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, detail);
        lv.setAdapter(imprimanteadapter);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Correct your English; can't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Sorry I have trouble with English , In fact when I press on my button for the list view of the printers this will show me the list of printers via the second page and what I would have liked is kept the second page to be able to do the same with the other buttons , What changes it is the query and arraylist, to avoid making more java page that would have the code structure except to display the data

Answer (score 0):

you can send the type as an extra with the intent so it will be like this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MaterielAssocie.this, Mat_asso_imp.class);
intent.putExtra("type","ordinateur"); // the type of material  
startActivity(intent);
```

and read the extra at the other activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String type = intent.getStringExtra("type");
//make your database request with type
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your class implement `View.onClick` and then put this nside your `Activity` only once:

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0){
     Intent intent = new Intent(MaterielAssocie.this, Mat_asso_imp.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     Log.i("List des ordinateurs","bouton de recherche pour le matériel");
     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
         toast.show();
}
```

and setup clickListeners like this:

```
btn_list_ordi.setOnClickListener(this);
other_button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: I do not know if this will help me, in fact what I would like is when I press a button it shows my list (this is what happens for the list of printers), which j 'Will like to do is when I click on the button that will display the list of computers that calls the same page except that the request changes and the arraylist too.